# Save time to convert when using web service

Tags: wcf

When I am using WebService, I have pass the value of DateTime using webservice then time is convert with -5:30 hrs. This means it shows UTC time. How to Save to change DateTime which i have passed in web service.

Comment: There is no ability do automatically convert time to UTC. 
You need to save the time in UTC like you are doing now.

Comment: But, when i am using webservice, then it automatic convert this into UTC time.

Comment: I am using web service for save and view.
Whan save webservice is call then it back to 5:30
and when view web service is call it again back to 5:30. This means when i am showing time then this is 11 hr back.